# Filter() is too slow on PowerPivot Query

Tags: mdx, powerpivot

I have a question regarding MDX code, I am trying to filter out values from a measure in my cube that contains several account numbers, however, the performance is too slow and I haven't been able to find a better solution than the following.

```
Filter
(
  [Cost Element].[ZCE Level08].[ZCE Level08].ALLMEMBERS
 ,
   Instr
     (
       [Cost Element].[ZCE.Level08].CurrentMember.Properties('Member_Caption')
                                     ,'A12600100'
     ) = 0

    AND 
      Instr
          (
             [Cost Element].[ZCE Level08].CurrentMember.Properties('Member_Caption')
                                     ,'A12600300'
          ) = 0
)
```

What this code achieves is to Filter out any rows that contain any of the accounts in the code, however it's a very large cube and I have to add 17 accounts more which makes this Filter reaaaally slow is there any better solution than this?

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

Ok there is a much faster approach - use the function `EXCEPT` instead of `FILTER` and make a set of the exceptions using the actual members rather than identifying them via `instr`:

```
EXCEPT
(
  [Cost Element].[ZCE Level08].[ZCE Level08].ALLMEMBERS
 ,
  {
    [Cost Element].[ZCE.Level08].[ZCE Level08].[A12600100],
    [Cost Element].[ZCE.Level08].[ZCE Level08].[A12600300]
  }
)
```

If you need to use `FILTER` then just to get rid of the member_caption / instr bit should speed things up a lot:

```
FILTER
(
  [Cost Element].[ZCE Level08].[ZCE Level08].ALLMEMBERS
 ,
   [Cost Element].[ZCE.Level08].CurrentMember
     IS NOT [Cost Element].[ZCE.Level08].[ZCE Level08].[A12600100]
   AND 
   [Cost Element].[ZCE.Level08].CurrentMember
     IS NOT [Cost Element].[ZCE.Level08].[ZCE Level08].[A12600300]
)
```